# Kotlin LiveData in object class

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have defined singleton in Kotlin as object class where I have connection to Room database and most logic is written in this class. I have defined LiveData, but its value is null, since there must be observer to work.

How can I implement observer in object class? Is this possible since function observe() takes Lifecycle as paramer?

Comment: Welcome to SO please post any relevant code, as well as any methods you have tried, in order to better answer your question!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
MutableLiveData<String>().observeForever {  }
```

method, which doesn't care about the lifecycle. Please post some code or better explain what you want to more relevant answer.